# Implementing Grid/table drawing algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

I'm trying to implement universal method for generating (drawing) grid formed with `UIView`s (or other controls). They all should have borders and my problem is I cannot find right algorithm to shift (*combine*) borders (so the "table" does not have double cell borders like now) and to increase size so the views exactly match given `frame` (red on picture).

Following code generates picture beneath:

```
////////
    const CGFloat kOuterBorderWidth = 0.0;
        const CGFloat kInnerBorderWidth = 1.0;
        NSArray *rows;
        NSArray *columns = rows = @[@0.065, @0.29, @0.29, @0.29, @0.065];
        NSMutableArray *cells = [self drawGridWithFrame:self.frame
                                                columns:columns
                                                   rows:rows
                                       outerBorderWidth:kOuterBorderWidth
                                      innerBordersWidth:kInnerBorderWidth];
///////
```

and the method itself

```
- (NSMutableArray*)drawGridWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
                             columns:(NSArray *)columns
                                rows:(NSArray *)rows
                    outerBorderWidth:(CGFloat)outerBorderWidth
                   innerBordersWidth:(CGFloat)innerBordersWidth
{
    CGFloat x = 0, y = 0;
    NSMutableArray *cells = [NSMutableArray new];

    CGFloat height = [rows[0] floatValue] * frame.size.height;

    for (int j = 0; j < columns.count; j++) {

        CGFloat width = [columns[j] floatValue] * frame.size.width;
        CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

        UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame];

        cellView.layer.borderWidth = innerBordersWidth;

        if (j == 0 || j == columns.count - 1) {
            cellView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor magentaColor].CGColor;
        }

        if (j == 1) {
            cellView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
        }

        if (j == 2) {
            cellView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor brownColor].CGColor;
        }

        [cells addObject:cellView];

        x += [columns[j] floatValue] * frame.size.width;

    }

    return cells;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Done it.

Note: `outerBorderWidth` is now not used here, if it is > 1.0pt, then we additionally should shift views and adjust their size

```
- (NSMutableArray*)drawGridWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
                             columns:(NSArray *)columns
                                rows:(NSArray *)rows
                    outerBorderWidth:(CGFloat)outerBorderWidth
                   innerBordersWidth:(CGFloat)innerBordersWidth
{
    CGFloat x = 0, y = 0;
    NSMutableArray *cells = [NSMutableArray new];

    CGFloat heightAdjust = (CGFloat)(rows.count - 1) / (CGFloat)rows.count;
    CGFloat widthAdjust = (CGFloat)(columns.count - 1) / (CGFloat)columns.count;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.count; i++) {
        CGFloat height = [rows[i] floatValue] * frame.size.height + innerBordersWidth * heightAdjust;

        for (int j = 0; j < columns.count; j++) {

            CGFloat width = [columns[j] floatValue] * frame.size.width + innerBordersWidth * widthAdjust;
            CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

            UIView *cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame];

            cellView.layer.borderWidth = innerBordersWidth;

            if (j == 0 || j == columns.count - 1) {
                cellView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor magentaColor].CGColor;
            }

            if (j == 1) {
                cellView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
            }

            if (j == 2) {
                cellView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor brownColor].CGColor;
            }

            [cells addObject:cellView];

            x += width - innerBordersWidth;
        }

        x = 0;
        y += height - innerBordersWidth;

    }

    return cells;
}
```

Result:

[image]